# WPF как очистить Source у Image Control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Мне нужно загружать картинку из бд и отображать ее на екране в контроле Image, после чего в определенном моменте мне нужно очищать Source тоесть путь к картинке что бы ее удалить и загрузить новую.

Свойство прибинденное к Source у Image:

```
private string photo;
public string Photo
{
   get { return photo; }
   set
   {
       photo = value;
       OnPropertyChanged("Photo");
   }
}
```

Очищаю путь к картинке и загружаю новую из бд:

```
// пытаюсь заставить сбросить путь
Photo = null;
// при попытке удаление вылазит ошибка "невозможно удалить так как используеться другим процесом"
File.Delete(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\Photo.png");
// загрузка картинки з бд на форму
if (SelectedVerstatOperator.Photo != null)
{
    ImageLoadFromDataBase(SelectedVerstatOperator.Photo);
}
```

Метод ImageLoadFromDataBase:

```
private void ImageLoadFromDataBase(byte[] image)
{
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(image))
    {
        // создаю новую картинку
        var photo = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
        // сохраняю ее на диск
        photo.Save(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\Photo.png");
        // задаю путь к картинке для отображения в Image
        Photo = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\Photo.png";
    }
}
```

Как заставить Image оставить в покое картинку? Что бы я ее удалил

Comment: Вам надо сначала загрузить другую след. картинку (или дежурную картинку-заглушку), а потом уже пытаться удалить предыдущую картинку. Иначе вы хоть свойство текстовое "обнулили", но `Image` все равно продолжает держать открытым файл картинки, а потому и не дает удалить ее.

Comment: @Bulson если не удалять то при сохранении в строке **photo.Save(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\Photo.png");** вылазит ошибка "В GDI+ возникла ошибка общего вида."

Comment: Тогда не надо использовать жестко заданное название файла изображения, используйте случайно сгенерированное имя файла `System.IO.Path.GetRandomFileName()`. Или воспользуйтесь ответом от @Squidward

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил так.
Сохраняю картинку с рандомным именем в папку Temp

```
private void LoadImageFromDataBase(byte[] image)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(image))
        {
            var photo = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
            string randomFileName = Path.GetRandomFileName();
            randomFileName = randomFileName.Replace(".", "");
            var path = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\Temp\\" + randomFileName + ".png";
            photo.Save(path);
            Photo = path;
        }
    }
```

А при закрыти программы удаляю папку Temp и заново создаю ее

```
string dir = System.Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\Temp";
System.IO.Directory.Delete(dir, true);
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);
```

Answer (score 3):

Нюанс в том, что XAML кэширует все изображения, не спрашивая на это разрешения. Чтобы избавиться от блокировки файла, нужно создать `BitmapImage` с `CacheOption` равным `BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad`. Сделать это можно либо напрямую в коде, и тогда забиндиться уже не на `string`, а на `BitmapImage`, либо с помощью конвертера.

Вот конвертер, написанный [Kent Boogaart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5380/kent-boogaart):

```
/// <summary>
/// This converter facilitates a couple of requirements around images. Firstly, it automatically disposes of image streams as soon as images
/// are loaded, thus avoiding file access exceptions when attempting to delete images. Secondly, it allows images to be decoded to specific
/// widths and / or heights, thus allowing memory to be saved where images will be scaled down from their original size.
/// </summary>
public sealed class BitmapFrameConverter : IValueConverter
{
    //doubles purely to facilitate easy data binding
    public double DecodePixelWidth { get; set; }
    public double DecodePixelHeight { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string path = value as string;

        if (path != null)
        {
            //create new stream and create bitmap frame
            BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
            bitmapImage.BeginInit();
            bitmapImage.StreamSource = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            bitmapImage.DecodePixelWidth = (int) DecodePixelWidth;
            bitmapImage.DecodePixelHeight = (int) DecodePixelHeight;
            //load the image now so we can immediately dispose of the stream
            bitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            bitmapImage.EndInit();

            //clean up the stream to avoid file access exceptions when attempting to delete images
            bitmapImage.StreamSource.Dispose();

            return bitmapImage;
        }
        else
        {
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }
}
```

См. [Delete image file used by XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2565784/293099).

Comment: А можно застримлайнить ваши свойства?

Comment: @VladD В смысле сделать автосвойства? Можно.